# How to ignore others messages if from_user has already sent a message?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my query

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user ORDER BY time ASC"
```

The problem is that it ignores `from_user` column and show more than 1 message from a single user, I would like to show only last message from each user which is in the column `from_user`, and show to the user logged which in the column `to_user`
how to ignore others messages if `from_user` has already sent a message?
I would like to select only last message `from_user` to `to_user`

I tried with limit but it select only a single user message which one is in the column `from_user` I need select by `to_user` but returns all single user messages inside `from_user` column

PHP code

```
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user ORDER BY time ASC";
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT from_user, messages.* FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user ORDER BY time ASC";
        $stm = $conexao_pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(':user', $user_logged);
        $stm->execute();
```

This is my columns from table `messages`
[image]

Comment: `WHERE to_user = :user ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1`

Comment: I tried with limit but it select only a single user message which one is in the column `from_user` I need select by `to_user` but returns all single user messages inside `from_user` column

Comment: Okay, you could try `SELECT DISTINCT to_user, * FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user ORDER BY time ASC`

Comment: Now it gives me a error in pdo `Call to a member function bindParam()`

Comment: I'd have to see your PHP code to diagnose that.

Comment: updated with the code

Comment: Try to get rid of `bindParam()`, just `$stm->execute(['user' => $user_logged]);`

Comment: still same problem

Comment: So even though you don't have `bindParam()` in your code, you are getting the error `Call to a member function bindParam()`?

Comment: `Call to a member function execute() `

Comment: Oh, syntax error in query is making `prepare()` return false. Try `SELECT DISTINCT to_user, messages.* FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user ORDER BY time ASC`

Comment: now works fine , but only selecting a single user from `from_user` column, I need select multiple DISTINCT users `from_user` column where `to_user = :user` I think you got me now

Comment: Oh, then just change to `DISTINCT from_user, messages.* ...` - It would be easier to understand if you provided example data in your question, example of how it's in the database and an example of expected output from query.

Comment: updates with a database picture of my columns inside message table, I changed to `from_user` works, but still selecting only a single user where `to_user` = :user , I need select multiple users inside `from_user` DISTINCT

Comment: I had to echo it inside a while now it works thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm understand the problem, I believe you must make use of the `GROUP BY` opreator and the solution should looks like this:

```php
SELECT Max(time), messages.* FROM messages WHERE to_user = :user
Group BY from_user
ORDER BY time ASC
```

(Your sample data should contain some related content)

**EDIT:**
Don't mix aggregate and non aggregate values in SELECT, see my comments below.

```sql
   SELECT 
      messages.* 
   FROM 
      messages 
   JOIN 
      (SELECT 
          from_user, MAX(time) MAX_TIME 
       FROM 
           messages 
       WHERE 
           to_user = :user 
       GROUP BY 
           from_user) MAX_QUERY 
    ON messages.from_user = MAX_QUERY.from_user 
       AND messages.time = MAX_QUERY.MAX_TIME 
    WHERE 
       to_user = :user;
```

Comment: still same problem, only selecting a single user `from_user` `WHERE to_user = :user` maybe I should inside a while or foreach?

Comment: I would like to create a subquery instead of a loop to avoid n+1 query proplem. 

(I'm not sure to fully understand the question in place, because of the missing sample data...)

Comment: So I should avoid while ? or not? it shows to me just fine now  only last message from each user

Comment: In context of db-operations you should (if a lot of loops and resulting queries are foreseeable).

Please take a look for `n+1 query problem`

Comment: I have a problem now, the messages it's not last message from user, how to fix?

Comment: PLEASE provide (anonymous) data suitable to reproduce the actual problem and desired behavior, then the real problem reveals itself and could be solved.

Comment: where can I send the sql file?

Comment: Please do it as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post)

Comment: Oh, I see the problem of my solution is mixing aggregate and non aggregate values. This leads to wrong (maybe random) non aggregate values beside the aggregate value as the result of the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Just for clarification about the `n+1 query problem`:

It's OK to loop over the result of a single query, but issuing a lot of queries while looping over the resultset of another query stresses the DB and should be avoided by building a composed query.

Comment: The solution is to `JOIN` the aggregate and non aggregate values together like this, as described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-partition-by-clause/). I edited my suggested solution.